# Best practice Java - String array constant and indexing it

Tags: java, strings, array

For string constants its usual to use a class with `final String` values. But whats the best practice for storing string array. I want to store different categories in a constant array and everytime a category has been selected, I want to know which category it belongs to and process based on that.

Addition : To make it more clear, I have a categories `A,B,C,D,E` which is a constant array. Whenever a user clicks one of the items(button will have those texts) I should know which item was clicked and do processing on that.

I can define an `enum`(say `cat`) and everytime do

```
if clickedItem == cat.A
 ....
else if clickedItem = cat.B
 ....
else if 
 ....
```

or even register listeners for each item seperately.

But I wanted to know the best practice for doing handling these kind of problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I much prefer using Enums to store system wide string constants, makes it easy to create additional functionality and I think it is generally accepted best practice.

```
public enum Cat {
     A() {
          @Override public void execute() { 
               System.out.println("A clicked"); 
          }
     },
     B() {
          @Override public void execute() { 
               System.out.println("B Clicked"); 
          }
     };
     //template method
     public abstract void execute();
}
```

then you can call it like so :

```
String clickedItem = "A";    
Cat.valueOf(clickedItem).execute(); //will print A is clicked
```

or you could also the Command pattern without enums....

```
public interface Cat {
     void do();
}

public class CatA() implements Cat {
     void do() {//put your code here}
}
public class CatB() implements Cat {
     void do() {//put your other code here}
}
```

then build a Map object and populate it with Cat instances:

```
catMap.put("A", new CatA());
catMap.put("B", new CatB());
```

then you can replace your if/else if chain with:

```
catMap.get(clickedItem).do();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your description is quite vague, so maybe I got this wrong, but it sounds as you could use a `Map<String,String>` storing your category relationships. E.g. if you have

```
class Foo {
   final static String[] cat1 = {"val1_1","val1_2","val1_3"};
   final static String[] cat2 = {"val2_1","val2_2"};
}
```

I would write:

```
class Foo {
  final static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
  {
     map.put("val1_1","cat1");
     map.put("val1_2","cat1");
     map.put("val1_3","cat1");
     map.put("val2_1","cat2");
     map.put("val2_2","cat2");
  } 
}
```

Then getting the category is as easy as calling `Foo.map.get("val1_1");`. Of course you should be a little bit more clever than me filling when filling the map (e.g. from a file or so). If you are concerned with changes of the map, wrap it using `Collections.unmodifiableMap`.

Comment: To guarantee that the values aren't modified, you could wrap the map with Collections.unmodifiableMap().

Answer (score -1):

As for your question - it is unclear what exactly you want to achieve, but I could just give you some general advices about using `enum`:

- An enum constant is an object and enum class name should start with uppercase (`Cat`)
- An enum is a fixed, finite set of enum constants. Don't use where you need variability.
- Enums can reference other objects. Final references of immutable objects are recommended. This can be very useful e.g. to store your string constants.
- Enum constant can be used as a map key, but also as a switch-case constant. It is definitely nicer than using a long if-else tree.